# iCloud lock - how to interpret the number of asterisks present

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I forgot my pin to my phone so I hooked it to my computer to do an update/restore.

When the update/restore was done, my phone is now icloud locked and I'm getting this screen:

[image: icloud lock screen]

I can't remember what email I used for this but my question is:

```
can "t*****@m*****.com" only be equal to something like
```

tjones@mjones.com (i.e., 5 characters where the asterisks are representing the number of characters)?

Or can it be:

```
tjohnson123214@mjohnson25345342343@co.uk
```

(i.e., (1) are the asterisks only a place-holder for any length of text? And (2) must it end in `.com` or was apple being lazy in how they designed this screen?)

Note this was updated to iOS 9.1 and the phone is an iPhone 4s.

Comment: Since you can't easily bypass this, you might need to regain access to the account. If you can edit this down to something more narrow - like how to log in to iCloud and reset activation lock remotely that might not be a duplicate on the site.

Comment: @bmike: my question is how to interpret the number of asterisks - I could not find that anywhere else on the site - I have hundreds of email addresses, I just want to narrow down which ones to try

Comment: OK - could you edit out the other "questions" and make it about that narrow idea? That edit will cause this to get reviewed for reopening. It's a little too broad for me to vote now to reopen it.

Comment: I revised the subject - is that what you meant?

I was only attempting to ask that one question in the body of my post

Answer (score 2):

The number of dots is not indicative of the number of characters missing at all—there could be 5, more than 5 or less than 5. The characters shown, however, are correct, including '.com'.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense - when I called apple to ask, they said the number of dots was indicative though the person I spoke to didn't sound too informed/smart (leading to me ask the smarter contributors here)